# Flash Scrolling through Movie Clip

Tags: flash, scroll, mousewheel

I am a novice programmer.

I would like to simply scroll through a flash movieclip using my mouse wheel.  Here is the work i've done thus far (http://www.stopitstudy.com/test.html).  Each image is a separate frame in a movie clip.

I had this working in Flash AS2 but then all of a sudden the web-page started scrolling around as well when scrolling with the mouse wheel.

I see there is a solution here: http://labs.byhook.com/2010/04/09/flash-mouse-wheel-support/

Is there someone that can make a basic .fla with description on how to use it???

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new layer in your FLA timeline file.  Select the first frame of this layer.  Open the "Actions" window.  Add this AS3 code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,mouseWheelHnd);

function mouseWheelHnd(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (e.delta > 0) {
        gotoAndStop( currentFrame + 1 );
    } else if  (e.delta < 0) {
        gotoAndStop( currentFrame - 1 );
    }
}
```